# Regex : Removing all extra whitespace, line-breaks, and empty spaces

Tags: php, regex

Update: It seems like it is just a regex problem.

I am trying to remove all extra whitespace, line-breaks, and empty spaces from user story with a function to grab only 100 characters

Issue is although 100 character limit works, the removing of whitespace, linebreaks and empty spaces does not apply:

```
function aboutme_echo($x, $length)
{ 
    if(strlen($x) <= $length) 
    { 
        echo $x; 
    }
    else
    {
        $y = substr($x,0,$length) . '...'; 
        echo $y; 
    } 
}

aboutme_echo((preg_replace("/\s+/"," ", $aboutme)), 100);
```

Example String: WHAT?! That's crazy!

Long story short,

someone reached out to me who had a pharma virus. 
I have the opportunity to rebuild their site, but I can't rush the planning and staging, but i...

Comment: Can you provide an example string and the expected result / count?

Comment: Added it, so yeah user input has a lot of whitespace and emojis sometimes...

Comment: What does `the removing of whitespace, linebreaks and empty spaces does not apply` mean? You are only searching for `spaces` in your regex. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8ee1be265d8d2107b6d27dd1714e5001578bc89

Comment: Your code works well, if you suggested to remove all of whitespaces etc, the second argument to `preg_replace` should be `''` instead of `' '`

Comment: You are right @waterloomatt - I am not familiar with Regex - I grabbed that code from https://escapequotes.net/php-remove-multiple-whitespaces/

Comment: I tried /\s+/gm - but it just deletes all characters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
function cleanExcerpt($string) {
   $pattern = '/\s+/';
   $replace = ' ';
   $cleanstring = trim(preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$string));
   return strtok(wordwrap($cleanstring, 100, "...\n"), "\n");
}
```

To use, you must pass through a string and echo the function like this:

```
$string = "Example String: WHAT?! That's crazy! Long story short, someone reached ";

echo cleanExcerpt($string);
```

Comment: This returns blank for me

Comment: @DLoy I updated my answer to include a use case for the function. It works, I've tested it several times. You just need to echo the function and make sure you are passing a string through it.